# Pandas - move data points from rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a df along the following lines:

```
Country Name    Indicator Name  value
0   Brazil            GDP         3
1   China             GDP         6
2   Germany           GDP         9
3   Brazil            Jobs        54
4   China             Jobs      12.8
5   Germany           Jobs      8.32
```

I wish to change it so that each Indicator will appear in a separate column:

```
Country Name        GDP     Jobs    
0   Brazil            3      54
1   China             6      12.8
2   Germany           9      8.32
```

How can I so? Should I transpose, pivot, or melt? And how exactly?
Many thanks.